# ADS (Advanced Design System) Simulation to fit experimental data

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, ads

I am a noob on ADS software. I was just wondering, if I have a given set of measurement data like the following:[image: Demo for the measurement vs fitting data]

And I know a equivalent RLC circuit model for my device, from literature. How do I optimize the RLC parameters in ADS so that the simulated output (say input impedance) can fit my experimentally measured data the best?

Thank you!